# Corona SDK 'nil value' issue

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I am making a shooter game using the corona sdk...
My problem is that i am trying to delete an object(that is part of an array)when it leaves the screen.. when i do, i get an error that says 'trying to compare nil value to variable' which refers to a simple move function for every object in the array. Here is relevant parts of code:

```
function addAlien()
    listeners('add')
end

function listeners(action)
    if(action == 'add') then
    Runtime:addEventListener('enterFrame',update)
enemyTimer = timer.performWithDelay(800,addEnemy,0)
    else
    Runtime:removeEventListener('enterFrame',update)
timer.cancel(enemyTimer)
  end
end

function addEnemy(e)
    enemy = display.newImage('drone.png')
    enemy.x = 500
    enemy.y = math.floor(math.random()*300)
    enemy:scale(-0.1,0.1)
    enemy.speed = math.random(2,6)
    enemies.insert(enemies,enemy)
    enemy.enterFrame = moveEnemy
    Runtime:addEventListener('enterFrame',enemy)
end

function moveEnemy(self,event) 
        --if self.x < 100 then
    ---self:removeSelf()
    --self = nil
    --removeSelf()
    --else
    self.x = self.x-self.speed
    --end
    end


function update(e)

       if(enemies.numChildren ~= 0)then
       for i = 1,enemies.numChildren do
       if(enemies[i] ~= nil)then
       --enemies[i].x = enemies[i].x-3
   if(enemies[i].x<100)then
   --enemies:remove(enemies[i])
   --display.remove(enemies[i])
   --enemies[i] = nil
       end
        end
     end
   end
end
```

I have commented out the parts that give me errors.
Any help would be appreciated,

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try and put the delete code in it's own function and then use a timer to remove it so that the function where you are currently deleting the object can return and you're not deleting yourself.

Another option would be to make it temporarily invisible and then loop through the table periodically and remove anything outside of the move handler.

Comment: well the problem isnt that i am delteting myself its that after the enemy gets deleted after it leaves the screen, the moveEnemy function doesnt reference anything, even though i am deleting only that particular enemy from the array...and the event listener for the moveEnemy is added anytime an enemy is created

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem with the following code:

```
function listeners(action)
    if(action == 'add') then
        Runtime:addEventListener('enterFrame',update)
        enemyTimer = timer.performWithDelay(800,addEnemy,0)
    else
        Runtime:removeEventListener('enterFrame',update)
        timer.cancel(enemyTimer)
    end
end
```

You only want to Runtime:addEventListener('enterFrame', update) once. If you do it everytime you add an enemy things will go wrong. The problem is your code runs again and again after the objects have been removed already.

Answer (score 0):

hmmm. did you use the scene template? if so, you should only put the :removeself () and = nil values in the scene destroy section at the bottom. you also dont need the second removeself that is not attached to an object as that is probably the nil issue.

to summarize.
1-put all remove self () and = nil at the destroy section of scene template and use object.isVisible = false instead.
2-the nil error is most likely coming from the removeself() statement with no object. so change it to moveenemy:removeself ()

Answer (score 0):

if my understanding is right this is how i would do it without using runtime
and using timer instead. ask away if you have question

```
local scrWidth = display.actualContentWidth
local scrHeight = display.actualContentHeight


local enemy = {} --this will hold your aliens

function addEnemy()
    enemy[#enemy + 1] = display.newImage("drone.png")
    enemy[#enemy].x = 500
    enemy[#enemy].y = math.floor(math.random()*300)
    enemy[#enemy]:scale(-0.1,0.1)
    enemy[#enemy].speed = math.random(2,6)
end


local function update()
    addEnemy()

   --this will move the enemy to the left from right
   for i=1,#enemy,1 do 
    enemy[i].x = enemy[i].x - enemy[i].speed
   end


   --the below codes will destroy each enemy that is out side the screen on the left
   local function destroyWhenOutside()
    for i=1,#enemy,1 do 
      if enemy[i].x < 0 - enemy[i].width then 
        enemy[i]:removeSelf()
        enemy[i] = nil
      elseif enemy[i].y < 0 - enemy[i].height then 
        enemy[i]:removeSelf()
        enemy[i] = nil
      end
    end
   end
   destroyWhenOutside()
end

--this will loop the update every 1/1000 seconds
local timerUpdate = timer.performWithDelay(1,update,-1)
```

.